# AdMob mediationReport.generate return type

Tags: admob, google-api-python-client, adsense-api

I am in between migration from AdSense API the AdMob API (mediationReport.generate method) to generate a report.

I am using python Client API

following below doc
https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/migration

it interesting the return type of statment(admob.accounts().networkReport().generate(
parent='accounts/{}'.format(publisher_id), body=request).execute()) is list when but my end goal to get data in CSV format.

the AdsenseAPI we can collect the data in dist and nicely collect the header, rows etc. is there any other way we can do the same in the new API.

PS: I am new to API programming so kindly excuse my knowledge.

Comment: check the python example on github: https://github.com/mprokhorenko/googleads-admob-examples/tree/master/python

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion about this on the AdMob API forum. If [this forum thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-api-developer-forum/c/RnTD6XzGFHo) doesn't answer your question, I'd recommend posting a follow-up there.